# Docker Save Image | Python SDK

Tags: docker

How can I save docker image locally in my system using python SDK. I know how to to export it via command line as mentioned over [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/).

However, I want to save the image (compressed form .tar.gz format) while running an python application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already created a client and able to communicate with the daemon `dockerd`.

```
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
```

You should be able to retrieve the running container by name or id:

```
>>> container_object = client.containers.get(name_or_id)
>>> container_image = container.image
```

The image object should have the method you are looking for as mentioned here: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.Image.save

```
 f = open('/tmp/someimage-latest.tar', 'wb')
 for chunk in container_image.save(chunk_size=2097152, named=False):
    f.write(chunk)
 f.close()
```

Worth mentioning that the `.save()` method will return a stream of raw archive data, that's why we specify `chunk_size`.

Comment: Thanks Saleem, however I want to save in compressed form

Comment: Yes, that's going to save a compressed  `.tar` archive file

Comment: Unless you mean something else when you say compressed

Comment: If I do .tar.gz format, the image size almost becomes half. Hence I was more looking with respect to .tar.gz format.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a `shutils` module , I think its shipped with python, you can use it to compress.